# Flutter custom package not loading fonts and images | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a package. I've added two directories, fonts and images, consecutive to the lib directory. I've also added the required code in pubspec.yaml file to use those fonts and images in the package. I created an example directory in the package directory in order to test the package I'm creating, but the test app won't pick the fonts and images from the package and gives the exception:

*FlutterError (Unable to load asset: images/abc.png)*

Screenshot of directories [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/po8oT.png

**pubspec.yaml:**

```
name: customtestingpackage
description: A new Flutter package project.
version: 0.0.1
author:
homepage:

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.17.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons:
  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/

  fonts:
    - family: Comfortaa
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/comfortaa/Comfortaa-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: fonts/comfortaa/Comfortaa-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
    - family: Poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/poppins/Poppins-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: fonts/poppins/Poppins-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
```

**main.dart:** *implementation of fonts*

```
style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
    color: Colors.white,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
    letterSpacing: 1.25,
),
```

Comment: did you stop the main.dart than run it again (not hot-reload) ?

Comment: did you make sure you did flutter pub get after modifying your pubspec.yaml? And you should also check if your indentation is correct.

Comment: any update here? I'm experiencing the same behaviour. Strangely it only fails to load the assets inside a flutter package project while it works in a "normal" flutter project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#from-packages:

> To load an image from a package dependency, the package argument must be provided to AssetImage.

> Assets used by the package itself should also be fetched using the package argument as above.

So in your case you should be able to load an image by something like this:

```
  Image.asset(
    'images/image_a.png',
    package: 'customtestingpackage',
  ),
```

The same seems to apply to fonts as well.
From: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html

> To use a font family defined in a package, the package argument must be provided

> If the package internally uses the font it defines, it should still specify the package argument when creating the text style as in the example above.

Comment: No problem! Would you mind marking my answer as accepted?

Comment: I have a base app with images under lib/assets/images and a whitelabel app with a dependency to the base app. When I use package: "baseapp" for images, they don't work anymore for the base app but they work for the whitelabel. Since they are under lib folder I have nothing specified in pubspec.yaml. Any clue?